# Bind icon images to their respective names then render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of amenities I am trying to map together each amenity with its respective icon then render afterward.

However, nothing is being rendered in the div with class `hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities`, it is empty instead of doing the loop and no error is being outputted.

Ideas on how I should go about this are appreciated

all the component code https://codepen.io/bihire/pen/abvBeqK

My function

```
import wifiIcon from '../../assets/icons/icons8-wi-fi-48.png'
import coffeeIcon from '../../assets/icons/icons8-cafe-50.png'
import AirCondIcon from '../../assets/icons/icons8-air-conditioner-64.png'
import defaultIcon from '../../assets/icons/button-circle-add-512.png'

const iconWithAmenities = [];

function AddIcon(aminityArray) {
    aminityArray.forEach(name=>{

        getIcon(name.toLowerCase());
        function getIcon(a) {
            var lookUpAmenities = {
                'free wifi': function () {
                    return iconWithAmenities.push({ name: name, icon: wifiIcon });
                },
                'free breakfast': function () {
                    return iconWithAmenities.push({ name: name, icon: coffeeIcon });
                },
                'air conditioning': function () {
                    return iconWithAmenities.push({ name: name, icon: AirCondIcon });
                },
                'default': function () {
                    return iconWithAmenities.push({ name: name, icon: defaultIcon });
                }
            };
            return (lookUpAmenities[a] || lookUpAmenities['default'])();
        }

    })
    return iconWithAmenities;
}
```

allAmenities array look like this `const allAmenities = ["Free wifi", "free breakfast", "free tv"]`

react render

```
<div className="hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities">
   {(AddIcon(allAmenities)).map((amenity, index)=> {
      <div key={index}>
        <div className="hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities_container">
          <div className="hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities_container_first">
            <div className="hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities_container_first_image">
             <img className="hoteCard_icon" src={amenity.icon} />
            </div>
            <div className="hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities_container_first_text">
                {amenity.name}
            </div>

          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     })}
 </div>


  [1]: https://codepen.io/bihire/pen/abvBeqK
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It seems as if the error is not related to the snippet you posted. Maybe the `Component` in the error refers to `React.Component` which you maybe forgot to import?

Comment: hh actually you are right, however, nothing is being rendered inside that div with class `hotel_card_flame_content_container_middle_container_amenities` it is empty @OPearl

Comment: OK. I can't figure out what's going on without a minimal working example.

Comment: I think  instead of const try to you use var i.e.``` var iconWithAmenities = []; ``` I think it will work

Comment: https://codepen.io/bihire/pen/abvBeqK @OPearl

Comment: I did try is still rendering nothing @PRADIPGORULE

Comment: @bihireboris, I think your codepen set up is wrong. I think you shouldn't import `React` and `Component` but use `class App extends react.Component`. Also, where are all the icons coming from?

Comment: sorry about that I just thought you wanted all the code I was working with @OPearl , however, I found the error It was the brackets on the callback function on map, they were supposed to be parenthesis . thanks for the will of trying to help tho

Answer (score 1):

Basically It was the brackets on the callback function on map

had to change this

```
 {(AddIcon(allAmenities)).map((amenity, index)=> {})}
```

to this

```
 {(AddIcon(allAmenities)).map((amenity, index)=> ())}
```